# Using SaltStack grains file with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, salt-stack, vagrant-plugin

I would like to use `minion.d/*.conf` to provision a vagrant machine.
Here is my Vagrant configuration:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ## Choose your base box
  config.vm.box = "precise64"

  ## For masterless, mount your salt file root
  config.vm.synced_folder "salt/roots/", "/srv/salt/"

  ## Use all the defaults:
  config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|

    salt.minion_config = "salt/minion"
    salt.run_highstate = true
    salt.grains_config = "salt/minion.d/vagrant.conf"

  end
end
```

After provisioning the Vagrant machine, I have errors with rendering SLS files since the `minion.d/*.conf` files are not being copied to the guest machine under :

```
/etc/salt/minion.d/
```

Should I make a sync config in the Vagrant configuration to co ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you just tried mounting a synced folder to `/etc/salt/grains`?

```
## For masterless, mount your salt file root
config.vm.synced_folder "salt/roots/", "/srv/salt/"
config.vm.synced_folder "salt/grains.d/", "/etc/salt/grains.d/"
```

Answer (score 3):

@Utah_Dave's solution will work just fine, or you can do the following (which is how I run it).

**Filesystem**:

```
/dev
  Vagrantfile
  salt-minion.conf
  salt/
    top.sls
    my-awesome-state/init.sls
  pillar/
    top.sls
    my-awesome-pillar.sls
```

**Vagrantfile**:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "mafro/jessie64-au-salt"

  # salt config directory & shared dir in /tmp
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/srv/salt"

  # setup the salt-minion
  config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
    salt.minion_config = "salt-minion.conf"
  end
end
```

**salt-minion.conf**

```
file_client: local

id: awesome

file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/salt

pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt/pillar
```

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant's implementation of **salt.grains_config** doesn't copy the file to the **/etc/salt/minion.d** folder as you might expect. Instead it copies the file to **/etc/salt/grains**.

To get the salt-minion to read this new **grains** file, you just need to add the following to your minion configuration:

## /etc/salt/minion

```
include:
  - /etc/salt/grains
```